# Convert Javascript string to Dictionary

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get Redis data in NodeJS. The Redis data needs to be converted to a dictionary for further processing. I gave it a try but finding difficult as parseFloat on string keeps giving me NaN.

Can anyone please help me to do it the correct way? Variable string has the sample data in below code. Please see the expected results below.

```js
var string = "[ '[Timestamp(\'2018-06-29 15:29:00\'), \'260.20\', \'260.40\', \'260.15\', \'260.30\']' ]";
string = string.replace("[", "");
string = string.replace("]", "");
string = string.replace("[", "");
string = string.replace("]", "");

s1 = string
var array = string.split(",");

var final = "{" + "\"date\"" + ":" + "\"" + array[0] + ",\"Open\"" + ":" + "\"" + array[1].trim() + "\"" + ",\"High\"" + ":" + "\"" + array[2].trim() + "\"" + ",\"Low\"" + ":" + "\"" + array[3].trim() + "\"" + ",\"Close\"" + ":" + "\"" + array[4].trim() + "\"" + "}";
console.log(final);
```

Expected Result:

```
{
    "date": " Timestamp('2018-06-29 15:29:00')",
    "Open": "260.20",
    "High": "260.40",
    "Low": "260.15",
    "Close": "260.30"
}
```

Comment: What output does your code produce?

Comment: @BenM Output of my code should be a dictionary which will be passed on to ag-grid

Comment: What does your *current* code produce?

Comment: @BenM Here is my current output           {"date":" 'Timestamp('2018-06-29 15:29:00'),"Open":"'260.20'","High":"'260.40'","Low":"'260.15'","Close":"'260.30''"}

Comment: You need to strip `"` chars from your values before passing them to `parseFloat()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra apostrophes at both sides of your string which is not needed and while parsing `parseFloat("'260.20'")`it returns `NaN`. You could remove them from the array as below:

```
array = array.map( (str) => str.replace(/'/g, '') );

parseFloat(array[1]); // 260.20
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be a whole lot easier to `split` the string by single-quotes, then combine into an object:

```js
const string = "[ '[Timestamp(\'2018-06-29 15:29:00\'), \'260.20\', \'260.40\', \'260.15\', \'260.30\']' ]";
const [,,timestamp,,Open,,High,,Low,,Close] = string.split("'");
const obj = {
  date: `Timestamp('${timestamp}')`,
  Open,
  High,
  Low,
  Close
}
console.log(obj);
```

Note that `\'` inside a string delimited by double-quotes doesn't do anything - it's the same as `'`. (If you need a literal backslash, use `\\`)

Comment: Thank you very much!! Appreciate your help!